# Is there any way to NOT get a Designer error when deleting code? (C#, Visual Studio, WinForms)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I'm making a WinForms program for my Diploma final project using C# and Visual Studio.

Sometimes I accidentally double-click a tool and that opens up the main event for the tool, like `button_Click`. But when I delete that code and check the Designer, it gives me an error message. If I choose to ignore it, all of the Form's formatting is lost and I have to start over (real pain in the a**).

I usually just click the `-` to minimise the code block and then add comments that the code is unused. But as you can guess, this makes for a really ugly and unorganised coding page.

Is there any way for me to remove the code and not get a Designer error?

Comment: undo all changes, go to properties of button, remove the event of button click from properties window itself and then re-build your changes.

Comment: You can also go to the code-generated page for the form and remove the line of code that hooks up the event there.

Comment: @noobprogrammer Build or Rebuild?

Comment: Either should work.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's when I get the error.

Comment: @ZaidHussain Rebuild.

Comment: Yup.  Because when it creates the event handler, it *also* hooks up the event handler.  You have to delete the code in both places.

Comment: An event that  you created accidentally is best removed from the __properties-events pane__ by deleting its name there. The code block is then removed, provided no code was added there..

Answer (score 5):

Go to the *Form*.**Designer.cs** file or <kbd>F12</kbd> on the `InitializeComponent()` method.

Then on the right margin look for the red dots and delete the events pointed to methods that have been deleted.

*Anyone got a quicker way?*

Comment: Best avoid the errors in the 1st place by removing the event names from the properties-events pane.

Comment: If you click the `Error List` Panel and pin it, you can use that list to quick-jump to the listed errors and fix them all. If you just added an event handler by mistake, you can also press `CTRL-Z` and undo it.

Comment: @Zaid: This is the actual way that most of the developers use to rectify the accidental double clicks. Also, when the Designer shows an error, **the formatting is never lost**. You should go to the Designer.cs file and check for errors, either remove or edit the errored lines. Voila! You got it sorted! If you don't have time to do this much, you can create a region in Visual Studio(https://markheath.net/post/visual-studio-regions), then add all unused events to the region block and you are done.